# how to override called function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried this with no success:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Web Page Design</title>
<head>
<script>
    function MyClass() {
        function someFunc() { calledFunc(); }
        function calledFunc() { document.writeln('orig called'); }
        return {
            someFunc: someFunc,
            calledFunc: calledFunc
        }
    }
    
    var obj = new MyClass();
    obj.someFunc();
    obj.calledFunc = function() { document.writeln("not orig called"); }
    obj.someFunc();
    
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I see that only `orig called` is called and not the `not orig called` how can i override the `calledFunc` so that the `not orig called` would get called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `obj.calledFunc` isn't the one you're calling inside `someFunc`.

You're replacing what `obj.calledFunc` refers to, but in `someFunc`, you're calling the one defined in the closure of `MyClass`.

You'll have to do something like:

```js
function MyClass() {
  var self = this;
  this.calledFunc = function() {
    document.writeln('orig called');
  };
  this.someFunc = function() {
    self.calledFunc(); // This refers to the same function you've exposed
  };
}

var obj = new MyClass();
obj.someFunc();
obj.calledFunc = function() {
  document.writeln("not orig called");
}
obj.someFunc();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to prepend `this.` to your call to the `calledFunc` method, because otherwise you're referencing the private `function calledFunc()`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Web Page Design</title>
<head>
<script>
    function MyClass() {
        function someFunc() { this.calledFunc(); }
        function calledFunc() { document.writeln('orig called'); }
        return {
            someFunc: someFunc,
            calledFunc: calledFunc
        }
    }
    
    var obj = new MyClass();
    obj.someFunc();
    obj.calledFunc = function() { document.writeln("not orig called"); }
    obj.someFunc();
    
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not define methods directly in an instantiated object (by a constructor function), since on every new instance you get a new copy in the memory. Use JavaScript's prototype concept. You can override the prototype's methods in an object. It will be invoked by a call to `obj.myFunction()` or `this.myFunction()` from inside. If it not not found in the instance, it will be looked up in the prototype chain. You can build multiple prototypes in a chain and so you can build an inheritance model. When you use the `Object.defineProperties` method, you further can control whether a property (methods are executable properties as well) is writable or not and other settings.

What you are trying in your example and some other answers illustrate, is not *overriding*, but *overwriting* methods. When *overwriting*, the original method is lost.

```js
MyClassPrototype = {};

Object.defineProperties(MyClassPrototype,
{
  'someFunc':
    {
      value: function()
             {
               this.calledFunc();
             }
    },

  'calledFunc':
    {
      value: function()
             {
               document.writeln('orig called<br>\n');
             },
      writable: true
    }

});


function MyClass()
{

}
MyClass.prototype = MyClassPrototype;


var obj = new MyClass();
obj.someFunc();

obj.calledFunc = function()
{
  document.writeln("not orig called AND...");
  // call original method with proper this-context (instantiated object)
  Object.getPrototypeOf(this).calledFunc.call(this);
}
obj.someFunc();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Titel</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```